# Loading 3D models Dynamically in iPad App

Tags: ios, unity-game-engine

I need to create an iPad app which can load 3D models(created using Unity) from the server dynamically(from a URL) and show. The 3D objects will not be inside the app during the compile time.

Please guide me on this, what are the options available to do this, and what are the libraries/technologies I should look at?
I've seen libraries like  iSGL3D Nineveh, Cocos3D etc.. But I'm not sure how to load the objects at run time.

- Can I do it using a WebService?
- Or using Unity Asset Bundles?
- Or any other better way to do that?

===================================================

From the replies I got , it seems asset bundles is the way to do it. So I created a unity project and then created a iOS project using it and was able to test the basics.

Now I want to integrate this with my existing app. Which is in XCode 5 and using ARC and storybords and coredata etc..

The iOS project which get created from Unity is not using ARC. So when I try to integrate these two, I get different errors which I don't get when I run these two projects individually.

I tried enabling ARC for the project and disabling ARC from the unity related classes using -fno-objc-arc. But still there are differnt types of errors.

So I feel there's a better way to do this. Can you please tell me what is the best way to integrate a project created from unity with another iOS project. If there's any documentation or a tutorial, it'll be really helpful.

Comment: Have you researched Asset Bundles? Do they suit your needs?

Comment: Look through Unity's asset store. I believe there are some run-time (as in not Unity Editor) 3D model loaders.  Or pick a simple format like Wavefront .obj and write your own.

Answer (score 1):

You sure can! First step is to package the assets into Asset Bundles:

> In some situations, it is useful to make an asset available to a
>   project without loading it in as part of a scene. For example, there
>   may be a character or other object that can appear in any scene of the
>   game but which will only be used infrequently (this might be a
>   "secret" feature, an error message or a highscore alert, say).
>   Furthermore, you may even want to load assets from a separate file or
>   URL to reduce initial download time or allow for interchangeable game
>   content.
>
> An Asset Bundle is an external collection of assets. You can have many
>   Asset Bundles and therefore many different external collections of
>   assets. These files exist outside of the built Unity player, usually
>   sitting on a web server for end-users to access dynamically.

See the full Unity Developer Knowledgebase [article on Asset Bundles here](http://docs.unity3d.com/Documentation/Manual/LoadingResourcesatRuntime.html).

Once you've learnt how to package assets into bundles, you can easily load them for use at runtime using the following example code:

```
function Start () {
    var www = WWW ("http:/myservermyBundle.unity3d");
    yield www;
    // Get the designated main asset and instantiate it.
    Instantiate(www.assetBundle.mainAsset);
}
```

See the full script reference [**here**](http://docs.unity3d.com/Documentation/ScriptReference/AssetBundle.html) for more information.

Comment: No problems. Please up-vote and tick this answer as successful if you found it has answered your question.